# Multiple coloured balls jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to make multiple balls fly across the screen random speed/location and changing random colour. I am coding it in javaScript/jQuery.

I have gotten one dot(div) to move random and change color, but can't create another div with the same functions - do you have a suggestion? (i am quite a noob and have just started javaScript/jQuery)

My code:

```
<html><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>balls</title>

<style>

.flip
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius:300px;
position:absolute;
}
.flip2
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius:300px;
position:absolute;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="flip"></div>


<div class="flip2"></div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();    
});


function makeNewPosition(){
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];       
};

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.flip').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateDiv(); 

    $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());         
    });   
};

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.flip2').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateDiv(); 

    $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());         
    });

};

function getRandomColor() { 
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); 
var color = '#'; 
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) 
{ color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]; 

    } 

return color; 

};

</script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for implementing OOPS  here :

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qbw6hsbj/2/

```
var Ball = function(element, nextPostion) {
    this._element = element;

    this.makeNewPosition = function() {
        var h = $(window).height() - nextPostion;
        var w = $(window).width() - nextPostion;

        var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
        var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

        return [nh, nw];
    }

    this.getRandomColor = function() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

        }

        return color;
    }

    this.animateDiv = function() {

        var newq = this.makeNewPosition(),
            self = this;

        this._element.animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, function() {
            self.animateDiv();

            self._element.css("background-color", self.getRandomColor());
        });

    }

}
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ball = new Ball($('.flip'), 50);
    ball.animateDiv();

    var ball2 = new Ball($('.flip2'), 40);
    ball2.animateDiv();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Function names in JavaScript must be unique.  Therefore, your second `animateDiv()` is overwriting the first.

You can combine both, like this:

```
function animateDiv(){
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $('.flip').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
    animateDiv(); 
    $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());         
  });   
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $('.flip2').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
    animateDiv(); 
    $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());         
  });
};
```

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qbw6hsbj/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function that you can treat like a class:

```
function flyingObject() {
    this.$div = [];
    return {
        $div: this.$div,
        animate: animateDiv
    }

    //Public Functions
    function animateDiv(){
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        this.$div.animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
            this.animate();
            this.$div.css("background-color", getRandomColor());         
        }.bind(this));   
    };

    //Private Functions
    function makeNewPosition(){
        //...     
    };

    function getRandomColor() { 
        //...
    } 
}
```

and you can instantiate it as such:

```
var div1 = new flyingObject();
div1.$div = $(".flip");
div1.animate();
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLqgs4dn/

Sidenote: since `animateDiv` is using a callback function, I used [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) so that `this` in the context of the callback function was still the object